# .net mvc linq jsonresult

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

Please look at the Code: how do i split the m.Division ("Divone,a") as object like ["DivOne","a"]

```
public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        var series = (from m in db.Fields.AsEnumerable()
                      where m.tstatus == true
                      select new
                      {
                          name = m.Name,
                          data = new [] { m.Division }
                      }).ToArray();

        return Json(series, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The Result

```
[{"name":"fff","data":["DivOne,a"]},{"name":"a","data":["a"]}]
```

I want the result Like

```
[{"name":"fff","data":["DivOne","a"]},{"name":"a","data":["a"]}]
```

image here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbKeX.jpg)

Comment: how things are stored in database can you show it in screenshot ?

Comment: try to change ``data`` to :``data = m.Division.Split(',')``

Answer (score 0):

Change m.Division to m.Division.Split(',')

```
 public JsonResult GetData()
        {
            var series = (from m in db.Fields.AsEnumerable()
                          where m.tstatus == true
                          select new
                          {
                              name = m.Name,
                              data = new[] { m.Division.Split(',') }
                          }).ToArray();

            return Json(series, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sajid

Thank you.... that is a result i wanted

```
public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        var series = (from m in db.Fields.AsEnumerable()
                      where m.tstatus == true
                      select new
                      {
                          name = m.Name,
                          data = m.Division.Split(',')
                      }).ToArray();

        return Json(series, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

[{"name":"fff","data":["DivOne","a"]},{"name":"a","data":["a"]}]

Answer (score 0):

just use Split(',') for division shown in below.

```
public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        var series = (from m in db.Fields.AsEnumerable()
                      where m.tstatus == true
                      select new
                      {
                          name = m.Name,
                          data = m.Division.Split(',')
                      }).ToArray();

        return Json(series, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```